# Getting Parcel Bundler Code Splitting working with React + TypeScript + MobX + ReactRouter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, parceljs

I've been trying to get Parcel Bundler to code split a ReactJS project for a while with no success, this project also used TypeScript, ReactRouter and MobX for its state management.

I've been meaning to put a boilerplate sample together and ask for help here for a while but not got round to it.

After a quick google earlier today, I came across a ready made boilerplate on Github which uses the same setup and also does not code split...

https://github.com/wenpengfei/parcel-typescript-react-boilerplate

Once compiled and ran, it just ends up with one big .js file in the dist folder, the idea behind code splitting is to create several smaller .js files per 'area' of the web application right?

Is this even possible with this combination of libraries/frameworks? If not, is my only option to go down the webpack route instead (if that will work?)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For client side code splitting just use `import` + `React.lazy`. Should work out of the box.

To support server-side code splitting (or client-side code splitting with server-side rendering) - https://github.com/theKashey/react-imported-component is the only choice for today.